# How can I prove $\gcd(10^{a-1}+10^{a-2}+\cdots+1, 10^{b-1}+10^{b-2}+\cdots+1)=10^{\gcd(a,b)-1}+10^{\gcd(a,b)-2}+\cdots+1$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I was solving $\gcd$ algorithm problem.

The problem was to get a $\gcd$ from two special numbers.

Followings are conditions.

1) User can input number $a$ and $b$

(maximum ciphers of a,b is 19. so type is must be unsinged long long

2) Two special numbers made by repetition of "1" as much as a,b.

ex) $a=4$, $b=3$ -> special number : 1111, 111

3) Finally, have to get a $\gcd$ of those two special numbers.

But I found specific relation between them.

Let special numbers by $a$, $b$ call $s_a$, $s_b$. then we can preset $s_a$, $s_b$ like below:
$$s_a=10^{a-1}+10^{a-2}+\dots+10^0\quad
\text{and}
\quad s_b=10^{b-1}+10^{b-2}+\dots+10^0.$$

From this, my foundation is below.
$$\gcd(s_a,s_b) = 10^{\gcd(a,b)-1}+10^{\gcd(a,b)-2}+\dots+10^0$$
but I can't prove why it works. Can you prove about this?

Sorry for my poor English. I'm korean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for any positive integer $n$,
$$(10-1)(10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+\cdots+1)=10^n-1$$
and therefore the problem is equivalent to
$$\gcd(10^{a}-1, 10^{b}-1)=10^{\gcd(a,b)}-1.$$
Moreover, if $a\geq b$ and $a=qb+r$ with $q\geq 1$, $0\leq r<b$, then 
$$\begin{align}
\gcd(10^{a}-1, 10^{b}-1)&=\gcd(10^{qb+r}-10^r+10^r-1, 10^{b}-1)\\&=\gcd(10^r(10^{qb}-1)+10^r-1, 10^{b}-1)\\&=\gcd(10^r-1, 10^{b}-1)
\end{align}$$
where in the last step we used the fact that $10^{b}-1$ divides $10^{qb}-1$. Now recall that the [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) computes the greatest common divisor.

Can you take it from here?

A more general statement holds: for $n\geq 2$ and $a,b\geq 1$,
$$\gcd(n^{a}-1, n^{b}-1)=n^{\gcd(a,b)}-1.$$
see [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1) .

Comment: Can u explain why first sentence equivalent to my question?

Comment: @BAEHARAM See the first line.

Comment: By the formula of sum of geometric sequence, I think the answer of first sentence is 10^(n-1)-1. Can u explain why 10^n-1? sorry.....

Comment: You are wrong. See the telescopic sum $(10-1)(10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+\cdots+1)=10^n-1$.

Comment: I understand that. But I really don't know why 10^r(10^qb-1)+10^r-1=10^r-1...

Comment: No, $10^r(10^qb-1)+10^r-1\not=10^r-1$. The gcd are equal. Recall the Euclid's algorithm and the property $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-nb,b)$.

Comment: How can gcd(a,b)=gcd(a−nb,b) apply to gcd(10r(10qb−1)+10r−1)=gcd(10r−1)?

Comment: We use $\gcd(A,B)=\gcd(A−NB,B)$ with $A=10^r(10^{qb}-1)+10^r-1$, $B=10^b-1$ and $N=10^r(10^{qb}-1)/(10^b-1)$ which is an integer number!

Comment: Thanks for great answer